# inline div not working

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to show a thumbnail picture and below the thumbnail, I want to have some text. Ideally I think I want to wrap the image and the text in a div whose style is set to be inline.

So imagine 3 pictures going across the screen from left to right and underneath each picture is a description of the picture.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Have you tried floating the container divs rather than using inline?

Comment: Pretty sure you accomplish that exactly how you said. You have your image/text combos each wrapped in a div that is set to inline.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle so we can see the state of you solution at the moment.

Comment: @user4145792 I assume you meant `inline-block`, not `inline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im with seb nukem here. I would use display inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this is by enclosing each image and description pair within a div element and then just floating those divs to the left.

**DEMO**: http://codepen.io/sajadtorkamani/pen/xbbrzE

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <p>Description goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <p>Description goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <p>Description goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put each image + caption within an inline or floating block:

CSS

```
div.image {
  display:inline-block; /* or use float:left; */
}
.caption {
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image"><!-- one div per image -->
  <img src="image.png">
  <div class="caption">Caption text here</div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="image2.png">
  <div class="caption">Caption text here</div>
</div>
...
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5s5s4otc/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the HTML `<table>` element.  Try something like this:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Description goes here.</td>
    <td>Description goes here.</td>
    <td>Description goes here.</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I hope this helps!  Leave a comment below if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pwee167/67oc6k7r/\

The outcome will be something like this:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/85/kids/128/thumbnail.png"/>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/85/kids/128/thumbnail.png"/>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/85/kids/128/thumbnail.png"/>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 128px;
}
```

---

**Note:** I assumed the dimensions of your thumbnails will be the same (as is in most use cases of thumbnails), which allowed me to set the maximum width (using `max-width`) of the container holding the image and the description. This will prevent the text from overflowing, and expanding the container.

Answer (score 0):

Use either float or inline-block on the container divs. See jFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ckk2jprr/

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg" />
        <div>This is some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg" />
        <div>This is some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg" />
        <div>This is some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pic{
    float: left;
}
```